# Detect changes in a tab delimited text file

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

I am new to Java ,I have a tab delimited text file , and I would like to scan each 5 minutes if there  were new lines added in the file. The new lines I would like to insert in an ArrayList , any hints ? thanks in advice !

Comment: Have you anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I guess you need to use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/).As using camel only for this purpose is not justice as it is a integration pattern but you can use it as it will make your work easy.Define a route and it will make the WATCH OF LOOKING FILE after every 5 mins.
Otherwise you need to write your own threads or work with [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).You can find a good example of [using timer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413656/java-how-to-use-timer-class-to-call-a-method-do-something-reset-timer-repeat)