# Is there a way to slow down a variable++; function?

Tags: java, timer

I need a variable to count upwards but in increments of 2 seconds. Right now I'm simply using a `++;` function, but as you know it's extremely fast.

Is there anything simple I can use to count at a slower pace?

Comment: `Thread.sleep( 2000 )` but it is not precise. You probably want something more like a `Timer`

Comment: Agree with @clcto, You should read [Java: How to use Timer class to call a method, do something, reset timer, repeat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413656/java-how-to-use-timer-class-to-call-a-method-do-something-reset-timer-repeat), could be help to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

This will make your program to wait for 2 seconds between this method call and whatever line of execution immediately follows this.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Count implements Runnable{
  public void run(){
     for(int i=0;i<=6;i+=2){
         Thread.sleep(2000)//in milliseconds ...sleeping for 2 sec
         sysout(...);//print your value
       }
   }
}
```

Start it this way

```
Runnable r=new Count();
Thread t=new Thread(r);
t.start(); // start the  thread
```

What you doing is basicly making a thread and running with a delay.I hope you get a concept

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pause the execution for two seconds by using Thread.sleep(2000).

```
//Your code...
Thread.sleep(2000);
counter = counter + 2;
//Your code...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print from 1 to 99, incrementing by 2 with a one second pause between increments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2) { // i = i + 2
    System.out.printf("i = %d\n", i); // print i = #
    try {
      Thread.sleep(2000); // two seconds.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```